# td width percentage not working notes client via pass-thru html

Tags: html, css, lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotus

I'm trying to show a table inside a computed text with pass-thru on in lotus notes client

here is the code of computed text:

```
<table width="100%" border="1px" style="table-layout:fixed">
<tr>
<td width="10%">test</td>
<td width="90%">test2</td>
</tr></table>
```

but in notes client I see the table divided almost in half

tried to switch the table width to 1000px, nothing happend
also tried to remove table-layout style from table - no matter

I'm stucked...

Comment: `<table style="width:100%">`. What do you think?

Comment: seems that in notes client pass-thru html width parameter in style attribute not working at all. table becomes in width of sum of widths of columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a [known problem in Notes 6](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21222378):

> **Question**
>
> The width attributes of HTML tables are ignored by Lotus Notes® 6 and later although these table width attributes are obeyed within Notes 5.
>
> ...
>
> **Answer**
>
> This issue was reported to Quality Engineering as SPR# DPOL6HRHRU and as not been fixed in version 8.0 but is approved for investigation for a future release.
>
> A possible work around for this issue is to create the table using LotusScript or in a third party application (such as MS Word) and then copy that table into the Notes document.

Answer (score 0):

it worked fine in my system..but you can try this also..remove the % ... try simply 10 amd 90....

```html
<table width="100%" border="1px" style="table-layout:fixed">
   <tr>
        <td width="10">test</td>
        <td width="90">test2</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: looking better without percent sign, but anyway it is not 10/90. it is about 20 percent. the width of table is 1030px, and width of first column is about 200. tried to change 10 to 5 - nothing changed. Did you tried this in notes client? which version?